How to handle time-based value objects in DDD when retrieving from persistent storage?
I have simple value object in my Entity called StartDate. It has simple validation rule, "StartDate" cannot be past.
public DateTime Value { get; }

public StartDate(DateTime value)
{
    
    if (value < DateTime.UtcNow)
        throw new StartDateCannotBePast(value);

    Value = value;
}

The problem is that upon retriving Entity from db "StartDate" is already in the past.
I had a simple idea. Just create value object using factory method without validating it.
Then in our config we could do something like that

builder.Property(e => e.StartDate).HasConversion(
    p => p.Value,
    p => ScheduleItemStartDate.CreateWithoutValidation(p));

Unfortunately this would allow us to create value object in our domain without validation.
So the question is:
Should I be pragmatic and just use this factory method, or is there a more proper way to achieve this

This isn't your fault; the literature sucks.


The problem is that upon retrieving Entity from db "StartDate" is already in the past.

Yes.
The short version is that you are modeling this "invariant" in the wrong place (as you have discovered).
The constructors/initializers of value objects are used both when we "create" a value (beginning of an object's lifecycle) and also again when we reconstitute an object (middle of an object's lifecycle), and therefore predicates that hold only at the beginning of an object's lifecycle have no business being enforced in the constructor.
It might be that what you really have is a detector of data entry errors (if the operator tries to schedule something in the past, that's probably a typo!) mixed in with your business logic, or it might be that you really have a policy driven from your domain... but that policy is only supposed to be enforced during the use case in which the StartDate is written down for the first time.
These two kinds of rules look superficially similar (if the date is wrong, then branch). but in terms of design (which is to say, creating code that has concerns properly separated, so that it is easy to modify when the needs of the business change) they are different, and it's important to notice the differences.
One heuristic that would help in this case is to remember that time is an input; if your domain models are tightly coupled to the system clock, then you are probably in the middle of a modeling error that should eventually be addressed.
